# Is it possible to do single sign on with Office 365 and third party web page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

Is it possible to do single sign on with Office 365 and third party web page?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh147177(v=office.14).aspx

Above link working in Console Application but in .net Page its not wroking

Comment: Why did you delete your other, identical question?

Comment: Because it's on hold and I don't know how to remove from hold

Comment: It will be removed from hold when you have made an edit to it that makes it fit the scope of this site and understandable. Everytime you edit a closed question it is added to a review queue where seasoned members will vote to reopen or leave closed. By deleting the old question and recreating it as a new post, you are circumventing that system, designed to keep the quality of this community high

Comment: Details here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: OK Got It... Thanks for knowledge. Do you have any suggestion for my question?

Comment: I would start here, with Azure AD apps: https://docs.microsoft.com/sv-se/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Office 365 uses Azure AD as users "database". Azure AD supports OAuth and you can use, for example, OpenID Connect for authentication and SSO with Office 365.

You can find sample here - [Calling a web API in a web app using Azure AD and OpenID Connect](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect). Under `https://github.com/Azure-Samples` you can find other samples for Azure AD.

You can also read about different authentication types and scenarios here - [Authentication Scenarios for Azure AD](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios)

Comment: hi Sergei, GitHub project doesn't using ClientContext. After doing SSO we need to do CRUD operation via ClientContext Object. Is it possible with SSO?

Comment: Hi, yes, it's possible. I answered on your original question, for further queries, please use separate thread.